# Disk image without wasting space

Tags: 12.04, server, backup

I own a single 12.04 LTS dedicated server hosted somewhere in the world by a private company. I have spent some time setting it up (web, DNS and mail services) and securing it. Now that I am satisfied with the result, I would like to make a disk image of the system partition, so that I can quickly reinstall a copy in case of HDD failure.

My system is setup as follow:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G  1.3G   17G   8% /
udev            984M  4.0K  984M   1% /dev
tmpfs           199M  280K  199M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        20G  1.3G   17G   8% /
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            994M     0  994M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda3       193G  1.2G  182G   1% /var
/dev/sda4       244G  1.4G  230G   1% /backup
/dev/sda3       193G  1.2G  182G   1% /var/www/clients/client2/web1/log
/dev/sda3       193G  1.2G  182G   1% /var/www/clients/client1/web2/log
/dev/sda3       193G  1.2G  182G   1% /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log
/dev/sda3       193G  1.2G  182G   1% /var/www/clients/client1/web4/log
/dev/sda3       193G  1.2G  182G   1% /var/www/clients/client1/web5/log
```

I have the possibility of booting the server from network, and of selectively mounting partitions. The plan is to mount `/dev/sda4` in `/backup` and to make a disk image of `/dev/sda1` in a file `/backup/diskimage`

**The issue is** : I would like the disk image to only store useful data (i.e. **I expect it to be 1.3G, not 20G**) so that I can later transfer it over internet to a backup location.
In case of a hard drive failure, I need to be able to quickly perform the process in reverse, and transferring the disk image to / from the server is the bottleneck.

*From what I understand, `dd` is not the right tool to build such disk image. What tool can I use ? How can I use it ?*

Would it be sufficient for me to:

1. TAR : /sbin, /bin, /etc, /ispconfig, /lib, /lib64, /opt, /root, /usr, /var
2. Plug in a new HDD, partition it exactly like the previous one
3. Install 12.04 LTS + all the packages I installed before (that can be automated and is fast)
4. THEN, untag all the folders above over my system.

Would it restore all the apache, postfix, etc… configuration **AS WELL AS the users and groups that were created on the system the first time with their UIDs** ? This is the key point that's keeping my current backup solution from working. Once restored, the server can't work because users such as `web1`, `client1`, etc… aren't created (so apache refuses to start). The issue is I have a lot of them, and I need to recreate them with the right UIDs and groups… here starts the nightmare...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conventional backup tool like `tar` or `dump`.

The main reason for doing an image type backup ( which you can do with clonezilla ), is that it can image the entire disk, including the boot loader, saving you the trouble of having to restore that as a separate step when restoring the backup.  Since you plan on only backing up the one partition however, that negates this advantage.

Other advantages of using tar include:

1. You don't have to unmount the partition to back it up
2. You can do incremental backups instead of having to repeat the full backup each time
3. You can extract specific files you may have changed or deleted from the backup, rather than having to restore the whole thing

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The partition I would like to backup is my "system" partition. I have sda1 (system) sda2 (swap) sda3 (/var) sda4 (backup). So I guess, my /boot is on sda1, as well as the kernel and other stuff. Can I just use tar to back it up and restore it mounted, while the system is running ? Or Can I use tar with my first plan (while booting from network ?) I mean : Before restoring on a new disk, I can partition it the same and install 12.04 LTS (takes about 15 minutes), then I can use tar to restore files, and I don't have to worry about booting stuffs. Would that work ?

Comment: I have added a few details regarding your answer in my first post.

Comment: @Adeline, you don't even have to install; you can just boot from the install cd, format the drive, untar, and reinstall grub.  See the link I added to my answer for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have read the link you provide and I have decided to go on with tar, just as you suggest. What has me lost is : if I follow the procedure you describe (i.e. boot from network, wipe the drive and untar the files) how does tar apply the correct permissions to all the files since the users that 'existed' in the old system (the one in the tar archive) do not exist currently (on the network-booted system)?

Comment: @Adeline, the "user" who owns the file is just an integer.  The mapping from that number to a name won't make sense ( i.e. tools can't translate it to a human readable name, so they will just show the number ) on the live booted system, but it doesn't have to.  Once you boot the restored system the names will make sense again since /etc/password will be restored to the state where it defines them.